# Adding AngularJS to Existing JQuery Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to add AngularJS to an existing template using JQuery (and lots of other plugins).  Currently it is an abysmal failure, and I've tried everything I can to get it to work.  Specifically, all of the "click to change" buttons do not work.

Here is what it should look like: http://www.shutterstiles.com/alpha/product-details-style5-2.html

Here is what it is doing: http://www.shutterstiles.com/alpha/#/product-details

You can see that none of the buttons work as they are originally intended and even the images don't load.  I don't have any errors in the console, so I'm completely lost.  I've tried changing the order things load, but that doesn't help.

Is there something obvious that I'm doing wrong?  I know that I shouldn't use AngularJS with JQuery, but I'm trying to integrate two applications into a single one.

TLDR; trying to get angularjs-route to work with template written for jquery.

**EDIT 1:**

Here is the main controller/route that I wrote to try to inject pages while keeping the header/footer the same.  I think this is breaking the JQuery on the other pages, because if I remove this it begins to work.

```
    var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);

    mainApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/home', {
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
                controller: 'MainController'
            })
        .when('/cart', {
                templateUrl: 'cart.html',
                controller: 'MainController'
            })
        .when('/account-1', {
          templateUrl: 'account-1.html',
                controller: 'MainController'
        })
            .when('/category', {
          templateUrl: 'category.html',
                controller: 'MainController'
        })
            .when('/product-details', {
          templateUrl: 'product-details.html',
                controller: 'MainController'
        })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/home'
            });
    });

    mainApp.run(function($rootScope, $location, $anchorScroll, $routeParams) {
      $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(newRoute, oldRoute) {
        $location.hash($routeParams.scrollTo);
        $anchorScroll();
      });
    })
    //This controller is the main controller of the entire website
    mainApp.controller('MainController', function($scope, $route) {
      $scope.isIndexPage = function() {
        return $location.path() === '/';
      }
      $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {     //Initialize sliders
            initSliders();
      });
    });

    //Initialize sliders
    function initSliders() {
        jQuery.fn.exists = function(){return this.length>0;}

        if ($('.slider-v1').exists()) {
            $('.slider-v1').cycle({             //Specify options
                    fx: 'scrollHorz',
                    //Name of transition effect
                    slides: '.slider-item',
                    timeout: 5000,
                    // set time for nex slide
                    speed: 1200,
                    easeIn: 'easeInOutExpo',
                    // easing
                    easeOut: 'easeInOutExpo',
                    pager: '#pager2',
                    //Selector for element to use as pager container
            });
        }
        if ($('.slider-v2').exists()) {
            $('.slider-v2').cycle({
                    //Specify options
                    fx: 'scrollHorz',
                    //Name of transition effect
                    slides: '.slider-item',
                    timeout: 5000,
                    // set time for nex slide
                    speed: 1200,
                    easeIn: 'easeInOutExpo',
                    // easing
                    easeOut: 'easeInOutExpo',
                    pager: '#pager',
                    //Selector for element to use as pager container
            });
        }
        // show loading image
        if ($('#loader_img').exists()) {
            $('#loader_img').show();
        }
        // main image loaded
        if ($('.sliderImg').exists()) {
            $('.sliderImg').load(function () {
                    // hide/remove the loading image
                    $('#loader_img').hide();
                });
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please share some code sinc eit is not easy to understand from your problem statement

Comment: There isn't much code to add.  The top page shows how the buttons load, and the bottom page shows none of the buttons/links work.